# accessDeniedPage redirect rather than just display the appropriate page RSS feed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 user roles - `user` and `admin` , if I go to a url where any authentication is needed and I am not authenticated - I get redirected to the login page, which is fine.

However, if I am logged in as `user`, and I try to access an `admin` only page, I get the home page displayed, but the url stays the same. I want to actually redirect to the home page rather than just display it.

```
...
.and()
    .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/")
```

So is there any way to make the `accessDeniedPage` method redirect, because as I said the home page **is** displayed but the url does not change.

Answer (score 0):

May be try following?

```
.and()
    .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("redirect:/")
```